# how to show two dimensional array in listview

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db=new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getrecord();
    c.moveToFirst();
    String[][] records = new String[c.getCount()][2]; 
    for(int i =0; i<c.getCount(); i++)
    {
        records[i][1]=c.getString(0);
        records[i][2]=c.getString(1);
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,records);
    setListAdapter(a);
}
```

i want to ask that, i want to show two record in one list like

```
id name
1  kashif
2  rana
```

Comment: what's your problem exactly ? For showing such listview you have to write custom layout for each row and ListAdapter extending BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

Just **create a Layout for the rows that consist of the two view that will display the information** for each of your rows, and the on the getview method insert the necessary data to each of the views. **look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial for a good head start.**